# Spring Boot trouble using the template engine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am quite new to thymeleaf but I am loving. I am having this issue that is bugging me a lot. 
I am trying to replicate the [Rich HTML email in Spring with Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html) inside my Spring Boot app. I am stuck at sending a simple email, not because of sending the email, but because of the templeteEngine.process method.

If I do:

```
final String htmlContent = "whatever"; 
message.setText(htmlContent, false); 
javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

I receive the email correctly.Although doing

```
final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process("mail/email-simple.html", ctx); 
message.setText(htmlContent, true /* isHtml */); 
javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

I get this error:

```
public java.lang.String com.example.controllers.MailController.sendSimpleMail(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Locale) throws javax.mail.MessagingException
```

Updated

```
[THYMELEAF][qtp320919849-46] Exception processing template "email-simple.html": Error resolving template "email-simple.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I tried these two alternatives

```
@Autowired 
private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine; 

@Autowired 
private TemplateEngine te;
```

I am not using any configurations btw, but I am pretty sure thats where the problem is. 
I tought i would be done by spring boot alone. Thanks

Comment: your "error" is a method signature, not an actual error. please provide the real error (stack traces etc.)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd it doesnt resolve my template. I using template/mail directory to store them. My controllers do resolve them. Just updated the question

Comment: From the sample you are using: `In order to process our templates, we will need to configure our TemplateEngine [...]`. Have you done that?

Comment: i tried to put     `private TemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
        TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("mail/");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        return templateResolver;
    }`

Comment: inside my `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` but that do not work. I do no want to do xml stuff

Comment: i though spring have handle at least some configuration for me because my web pages are working

Comment: Try dropping the `.html` extension from your method call.

Comment: That was it @chrylis ! Dropped the emailTemplateResolver too, that was unnecessary in my case. I would be happy to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the Thymeleaf engine configured by Boot is configured with a prefix of `/templates/` and a suffix of `.html`. Don't include those bits in the template name; just use `"mail/email-simple"`.